# mercurial update leads to abort (filename too long)

Tags: mercurial, symlink

After creating a symlink to a file I checked the file into my repo and it worked fine up to the point when I shared the repo with my teammate who is using Windows (his code goes into branch 'devui', mine is on the default branch).

If I switch from his latest changes (being on branch 'devui') to my default branch using `hg upd default` I get this message:

```
abort: could not symlink to '...<complete contents of symlinked file here>...':
File name too long: <symlink-filename>
```

This occurs after about half of the checkout so only a part of the files will be updated and the rest of the files (after the abort) is missing.

I also tried a fresh clone and `hg upd -C default` leading to the same result. In the moment my 'default' branch is in an unusable state and I cannot get back to my branch. I *can* get back to the revision before the 'devui'-branch was created though.

So my question is: Is it possible to skip the bad symlink, ignoring the abort and continue with the rest of the files? (I could recover that file easily).

I'm using mercurial 2.3 on MacOSX (via brew).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/hg-clone-fails-with-abort-could-not-symlink-to-td801496.html) from 2010 (much older version of mercurial) suggests cloning the repo on a windows box, which may be unaffected by the problem, and reverting the symlink there.